# Where is the adra arch in Sagani "The Long Hunt" Part 2?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

Where is the adra arch in the forest that the second part of the quest references?? I've checked all my maps and I can't for the life of me find it.

Answer (score 1):

South west in the Elmshore area.